# Intents extras arent' passed in my modified master/detail template

Tags: android, android-intent, master-detail, extra

I'm trying to modify a stock Master / Detail template in Android Studio. My main goal is to try and display properly the simple `List<Obj>`, which I populate manually in the `onCreate()`.
My problem is that the extras which should be passed from `ListActivity` to `DetailActivity` (and then passed to Fragment) do not pass.

Full code [here](https://github.com/keehoo/MasterDetail_training)

I suspect there's something wrong with the RecyclerView Adapter (and holder) that I modifed. I also do not like to out-of-stock DummyContent class.

I'd also appreicate your opinion whether it's better to remove this DummyContent class and create your own data source or it's just easier and more convenient in so called real life to modify the existing Dummy content source.

If you prefer to have more code snippets pasted here, please let me know, thank you in advance for you help.

```
 public class SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<Obj> mValues;

    public SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Obj> items) {
        mValues = items;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.data_list_content, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.obj = mValues.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(holder.obj.getName());
        holder.image.setText(holder.obj.getImage());

        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mTwoPane) {
                    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                    arguments.putString(Keys.KLUCZ, holder.obj.getName());  // tutaj musze przeslac Id
                    DataDetailFragment fragment = new DataDetailFragment();
                    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.data_detail_container, fragment)
                            .commit();
                } else {
                    Context context = v.getContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DataDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(Keys.KLUCZ, holder.obj.getName());
                    Log.d("DataListActivity", "obj.getName = "+holder.obj.getName());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final TextView name;
        public final TextView image;
        public final View mView;
        public Obj obj;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
            image = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
        }

    }
```

And the receiving Activity:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Create the detail fragment and add it to the activity
        // using a fragment transaction.
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(Keys.KLUCZ,
                getIntent().getStringExtra(Keys.KLUCZ));
        DataDetailFragment fragment = new DataDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.data_detail_container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself:
I was instantiating my Obj object incorrectly:

was:

```
mItem = new Obj(Keys.KLUCZ, "some string");
```

should be:

```
mItem = new Obj(getArguments().getString(Keys.KLUCZ), "Jakies nazwisko");
```